# How can I update Child records from list of Parent Records in custom controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, custom-controller, childrecords

I have a custom controller with a list of parent records (opportunities) and a list of their child records (opportunitylineitems). I want to save both the parent fields and child fields with one button. I know my update method needs to add the child list but I don't know how to get the child list to update.

Here is my code.

Controller

```
    public PageReference getopps()
{

    Set<String> oppids = new Set<String>();
        for (OpportunityLineItem oline : opps) oppids.add(oline.opportunityId);

    oppparents = [Select Id, StageName,Opportunity_Notes__c,Manager_Note__c,AccountId, Account.Name
                  ,name,Resellers_and_Type__c,(SELECT Quantity,Product2Id,product2.Name,ServiceDate
                                               ,Ship_Out_Date__c FROM OpportunityLineItems)                         
                  from opportunity where id in: oppids order by name];


    system.debug(opps);

    return null;

} 
public PageReference updateopps(){  
   //save the opportunities after update or send error message to admin


    update oppparents;
}
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
   <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!getopps}" rerender="block" status="status" oncomplete="pos();"/>
   <apex:commandButton value="Save & Update" action="{!updateopps}" rerender="block" status="status"/>

    <apex:pageBlockSection id="sect2" >
      <apex:outputLabel for="oenduser" style="float:right;margin-right:150px;">End User&nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <apex:inputText id="oenduser" value="{!oppenduser}" onkeypress="return onKeyup_TxtFieldcom(event);"/></apex:outputLabel>
      <apex:outputLabel for="oreseller" style="float:right;margin-right:150px;">Reseller&nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <apex:inputText id="oreseller" value="{!oppreseller}" onkeypress="return onKeyup_TxtFieldcom(event);"/></apex:outputLabel>
      <apex:outputLabel for="oproduct" style="float:right;margin-right:150px;">Product Sku&nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <apex:inputText id="oproduct" value="{!oppprod}" onkeypress="return 
onKeyup_TxtFieldcom(event);"/></apex:outputLabel> 
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
    </apex:pageBlockSection><br/>

    <apex:actionFunction name="search" action="{!getopps}" rerender="block" 
status="status"/>

  <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Searching... please wait..."/>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Results" id="resultsBlock" columns="1">
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppparents}" var="opp" rendered="
{!NOT(ISNULL(oppparents))}">
       <apex:column headerValue="End User" width="100">
      <apex:outputLink value="/{!opp.Id}">{!opp.Account.Name}
</apex:outputLink>

      </apex:column>
      <apex:column headerValue="Resellers" width="100">
        <apex:outputfield value="{!opp.Resellers_and_Type__c}" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
            <apex:dataTable value="{!opp.OpportunityLineItems}" var="item" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(opps))}" id="lineitems">
                <apex:column headerValue="Product" width="200">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!item.Product2.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" width="200">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Quantity}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Ship Out Date" width="200">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Ship_Out_Date__c}"/>
            </apex:column>    
           </apex:dataTable>
      </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="Stage" width="100">
        <apex:inputfield value="{!opp.StageName}" />
      </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="Pipeline Notes" width="100">
        <apex:inputfield value="{!opp.Opportunity_Notes__c}" />
      </apex:column>           



        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: put only relevant code with the context of your question. and first give a try at  your end

Comment: Sorry. I edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updateOpps method, you need to loop through the opps, build a list of OppLineItems, then update that list.  Something like this:

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
  olis.addAll(opp.OpportunityLineItems);
}
update olis;
```

Comment: This is at the most a comment as specified in [answer], please include details as to how/what the user should do alongside any code with explanations. Thanks!