# How to update Child Records based on Parent Record in Apex Controller

Tags: apex, custom-controller

I am writing an inline visualforce page to update parent records and their child records.

I am making an inline visualforce page where users can edit and update records from parent and child objects which are displaying on the same row. One line by parent with the parent records and their child records.

A parent can have several children.

I can save parent modifications but I can't save child modifications.

The controller is like this :

```
public class inlineDetail {


    public List<Contact> contactsList = new List<Contact>();


    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        contactsList = [SELECT Name,accountId,Phone,AssistantPhone,Email, (SELECT Name, Classroom__c, Comments__c from Courses__r) FROM Contact ORDER BY Name];
        return contactsList;
    }

    public void saveChanges() {
        update contactsList;
        List<course__c> coursesList = new List<course__c>();
        for (Contact c : ???) {
            coursesList.addAll(c.Courses__r);
        }
        update coursesList;
    }

}
```

The visualforce page is like this :

```
<!-- Shows a table of contacts associated with courses.
The contact column headers are controlled by the facets.-->

<apex:page controller="inlineDetail" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts" mode="inlineEdit">

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!saveChanges}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="s">
        <!-- width="100%" cellPadding="4" border="1" --> 

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!s.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Account</apex:facet>
                    {!s.accountId}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Phone</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!s.Phone}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Phone Assistant</apex:facet>
                {!s.AssistantPhone}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">eMail</apex:facet>
                {!s.email}
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Course</apex:facet>
                        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!s.Courses__r}" var="c">
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Name}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                {!c.Classroom__c}
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Comments__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                </apex:pageblocktable>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I find [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188787/how-can-i-update-child-records-from-list-of-parent-records-in-custom-controller) but I can't see how to start.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. This question doesn't seem to actually be related to your VF, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the child records before you update the parent. So in your `saveChanges()` method you should create a list of Course__c and call update on that list.

```
List<Course__c> courses = new List<Course__c>();
for (Contact c : contactsList) {
    courses.addAll(c.Courses__r);
}
update courses;
update contactsList;
```

Comment: Ok. I will give a try at this solution. Thank you.

Comment: I have an error like this : "Variable does not exist: contactList".

How can I declare this variable?

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you.

Just done a correction for "contactList" in ."for (Contact c : contactsList) {"

`List<Course__c> courses = new List<Course__c>();
for (Contact c : contactsList) {
    courses.addAll(c.Courses__r);
}
update courses;
update contactsList;`

Is it correct coding?

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer to use the correct variable name as well.